# I want to create a subtitle site

Tags: web-applications

I really want to create a simple subtitle site which has a simple features like user login/logout, upload, search, rate.

http://tinysubs.com/ seems a ideal interface for me. It meets user's wanted right at the moment.

So where should I start, what framework should I use:

- I prefer python, php
- A tutorial will be extremely useful
- Source of the same project will be
  great

Thanks first

Answer (score 1):

prefer a **CMS** rather than building your own

1. Start with a CMS. Choose a CMS that suits your requirment like custom post types, file attachments, login required to download, etc. Evaluate **Drupal, Joomla**, etc
2. Figure out what are the properties (meta information) a subtitle object has.
3. Build custom type in your chosen CMS. Customize its look and feel i.e. theme/style
4. Optimize the site using cache, seo friendly urls, etc; Find our CMS's extensions that are useful to you.
5. Later when you grow traffic and feel you need some specific features you can write your own extensions/modules.